# How to free the memory occupied by a particular process?

Tags: ram, memory-usage, cleanup

I was load testing my selenium with chromedriver and geckodriver, and tried to open 100 browser instances. The system crashed for sometime and then it became alright. But the memory occupied by the chromedriver and geckodriver are still not freed.

I came to know this when I checked the system monitor. [image: driver instances]

I ran the `free -m` command to know how much memory is left. It showed

```
              total        used        free      shared  buff/cache   available
Mem:          15920       13182        1539         482        1199        1613
Swap:             0           0           0
```

So I need to clear the memory occupied by chromedriver and geckodriver alone. How can I do this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You simply need to terminate all those processes, as they're still somehow running in background.

Either use the System Monitor to end them, or run in a terminal:

```
killall chromedriver geckodriver
```

If that does not manage to terminate the processes (semi-) gracefully because they're stuck badly, you can forcefully kill them instead with

```
killall -KILL chromedriver geckodriver
```

Comment: That works, thank you.